# How do I continue a content to a next page in Reportlabs - Python

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, reportlab

I'm making a table, where the table can be either small or large depending upon the data being received.

While I was providing a huge data set, I noticed that although the table is being made but my all content is not there, since it occupies only 1 page for that.

So, my question is How do I continue a content to a next page in Reportlabs without using `showpage()` , since I wont be able to know when to hit `showpage` or when not, because the content is being dynamically generated?

**Code**

```
def plot_table(pie_labels, pie_data, city_devices):
    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
    styleN = styles["BodyText"]
    styleN.alignment = TA_LEFT
    styleBH = styles["Normal"]
    styleBH.alignment = TA_CENTER

    city_name = Paragraph('''<b>City Name</b>''', styleBH)
    meter_name = Paragraph('''<b>Meter Name</b>''', styleBH)
    consumption = Paragraph('''<b>Total Consumption</b>''', styleBH)

    data= [[city_name, meter_name, consumption]]
    # Texts
    for label,record,device in zip(pie_labels,pie_data,city_devices):
        label = Paragraph(label, styleN)
        record = Paragraph(str(record), styleN)
        device_list = ""
        for d in device:
            device_list += str(d) + ", "
        device = Paragraph(device_list, styleN)
        data.append([label, device, record])

    table = Table(data, colWidths=[5.05 * cm, 5.7 * cm, 3* cm ])

    table.setStyle(TableStyle([('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                               ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                              ]))
    return table


table = plot_table(pie_labels, pie_data, city_devices)
table.wrapOn(the_canvas, width, height)
table.drawOn(the_canvas, *coord(2, 59.6, cm))
```

Comment: I have the same question..It's interesting to know the answer..

Answer (score 2):

I'd advice using the more high-level primitives of reportlab, that is, document templates, frames and flowables. That way, you get splitting for "free". [An example from the related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271370/how-to-repeat-table-column-headings-over-page-breaks-in-pdf-output-from-reportla#answer-9287835)

Answer (score 0):

Use `table.split()`:

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4 # im using A4

width, height = A4
table_pieces = table.split(width, height)

for table_piece in table_pieces:
    table_piece.drawOn(the_canvas, *coordinates)
    the_canvas.show_page()
the_canvas.save()
```

Tell me if it helped :)

Comment: No, its not working. I still get the data which is limited to only 1 page. Other data gets cut-off..