# xlswriter - Python module to create excel files

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I m working with xlswriter to generate Excel files in python. I'm referring [this link] for tutorial.

In this under section **Chart series option: Points**, I copied the code and ran it. it works but I need to remove the following lines as they are not required.

```
worksheet.write_column('A1', data[0])
worksheet.write_column('B1', data[1])
```

These lines give me the values of the pie chart data in textua format in cells A1 and B1, which I dont want.

But when I remove them, the pie chart also gets removed. I dont know why. Where I'm going wrong

Here is the code.

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart_pie.xlsx')

worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'pie'})

data = [
    ['Pass', 'Fail'],
    [90, 10],
]

worksheet.write_column('A1', data[0])# these lines gets printed on top left corner, which I dont want.
worksheet.write_column('B1', data[1])

chart.add_series({
    'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$2',
    'values':     '=Sheet1!$B$1:$B$2',
    'points': [
        {'fill': {'color': 'green'}},
        {'fill': {'color': 'red'}},
    ],
})

worksheet.insert_chart('C3', chart)

workbook.close()
```

Comment: I guess you can't have chart without underlying data. How would you do in excel itself?!

Comment: The reason the chart gets removed is because the chart is plotting the values from those cells. This `=Sheet1!$A1:$A$2` and `=Sheet1!$B1:$B$2` refer to the values from those cells.

Comment: I got your point that I cannot get the chart without having the data for that, but I dont want that data to be printed in cells A1 and B1. Any suggestions how I remove that from cells A1 and B1. Thanks

Comment: On the other hand can you please have a look at this thread as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488563/python-convert-pdf-to-excel-in-python

Comment: You can't _delete_ it, you can move it to another area of the sheet; so decide where you want it to show and then adjust the values accordingly. If you just want to generate a graph, there are easier ways to do that.

Comment: Can you please provide your suggestions on this thread. Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416078/how-do-i-continue-a-content-to-a-next-page-in-reportlabs-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can add the data to another worksheet. And then refer the data from that worksheet.

**Demo**

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart_line.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()
# Add the worksheet data to be plotted.
data = [10, 40, 50, 20, 10, 50]
worksheet1.write_column('A1', data)

# Create a new chart object.
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

# Add a series to the chart.
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet2!$A$1:$A$6'})

# Insert the chart into the worksheet.
worksheet.insert_chart('C1', chart)

workbook.close()
```