# Generating repeating column headers with reportlab

Tags: python, pandas, pdf-generation, reportlab

I recently started using `reportlab` with `Python` to generate PDFs from a `Pandas DataFrame` with page numbers and clickable TOC. My problem right now is that some tables extend to the next page, and hence the headers do not show on the next page. I would like to repeat the column headers and colours with it before the extended rows are repeated. I have tried everything on this but nothing works. Has anyone had a similar issue? Or does anyone have an idea on the way to go about this? I would really appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case you are also wondering how to solve this issue. I found an answer on Stackoverflow, here: [How to Repeat Table Column Headings over Page Breaks in PDF output from ReportLab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271370/how-to-repeat-table-column-headings-over-page-breaks-in-pdf-output-from-reportla)